# How to broadcast a complex class object in pyspark across the clusters

Tags: python, c++, c++11, apache-spark, pyspark

Following is the code where `py_cpp_bind` refers to a piece of code written in `C++11` and then binded to python using `boost-python` (enabled pickling). In order to initialize the object it requires three arguments `(filename, int, int)`. I wished to broadcast this object across the clusters, as this piece is required to perform a computation for each element.

However, on execution Apache Spark seems to complain with

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    ... 15 more
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.serializers import BatchedSerializer, PickleSerializer
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import py_cpp_bind


def populate_NL(n, tk2):
    tk = [list(tk2[0]), tk2[1]] 
    res = mscore.score(tk[1], tk[0])

    return res  


def main(n, sc):
    mscore = py_cpp_bind.score()
    # following line constructs the object from the given arguments
    print mscore.init("data/earthquake.csv", n, 4000)

    broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(mdl)

    C = [((0,), [1])]
    C = sc.parallelize(C).flatMap(lambda X : populate(n, X))
    print(C.collect())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
    conf = conf.setAppName("TEST")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf, serializer=PickleSerializer())
    n = 5
    main(n, sc)
```